# Error Cannot create instance of abstract (non-instantiable) type `GtkBox' python3

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I have error when run this code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="")
        # box
        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.add(self.box)
        # bacon button
        self.bacon_button = Gtk.Button(label="Bacon")
        self.bacon_button.connect("clicked", self.bacon_clicked)
        self.box.pack_start(self.bacon_button, True, True,0)
        # tuna button
        self.tuna_button = Gtk.Button(label="Tuna")
        self.tuna_button.connect("clicked", self.tuna_clicked)
        self.box.pack_start(self.tuna_button, True, True,0)
    def bacon_clicked(self, widget):
        print("You clicked Bacon")
    def tuna_clicked(self, widget):
        print("You clicked Tuna")

window = MainWindow()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

And error at output:

```
  File "/Users/*********/Documents/Program/Tutorial/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 319, in new_init
    return super_init_func(self, **new_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot create instance of abstract (non-instantiable) type `GtkBox'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I currently using python3 and already install PyGObject package in PyCharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is loading GTK2, instead of GTK3; in GTK 2.x, `GtkBox` is indeed an abstract type.

If you want to use GTK 3.x, you will need to add:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
```

at the top, before importing the Gtk namespace.

Comment: I've tried it. Error appears:

raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available for version %s' %
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available for version 3.0

Comment: You need to install GTK3 and its introspection data, if you want to use GTK3.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Box directly. If you want a Box that grows horizontally with `pack_start`, use `Gtk.HBox` (documented [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/HBox.html)).

If you want it to grow vertically, use `Gtk.VBox` (documented [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/VBox.html)).

That being said, the more modern (GTK4) way of doing things is to use a `Gtk.Grid` for everything.

Comment: HBox and VBox are deprecated types from GTK2, used only for easing the port of older applications.